# Why can't instantiate object from AudioManager with new operator?

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I am novice with the android. I am learning how to make audio and control the voice of this audio with `AudioManager` class. But I have a simple question, according to the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) of the android developers it says that

> AudoiManager is a public class AudioManager extends Object and to
>   instantiate an object from this class Use
>   Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)

I got confused here Why we can't instantiate this class with the `new` operator and what does `Context` have to do with this?

Comment: You can't instantiate that class most likely because it wasn't designed with public constructors. And it doesn't have public constructors most likely because `AudioManager` needs some very system-specific data to work properly, and developers are relieved from the need to guess what that data is.

Comment: `Context.getSystemService` is also not required to return a new object every time - all apps on the device can get the same `AudioManager` instance.

Comment: thank you for the good explanation @M.Prokhorov

Answer (score 2):

Since this question concerns AudioManager object in Android, I would also like to add how you can achieve this using Kotlin as well since I had same challenge and I managed to sort using the below approach.

```
private lateinit var audioManager: AudioManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity)

    audioManager = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
//...your other codes
}
```